# Реализация метода Remove для своей коллекции на базе массива

Tags: c#, .net

Как реализовать для своей коллекции метод `Remove(T item)` (такой же, как в `List<>`), удаляющий указанный элемент, но не меняющий реальной емкости массива?

У меня есть коллекция и ее параметры:

```
T[] arreay = new T[5];

public int count;
public int size;

public void Insert(int index, T item)
{
    size++;
    T[] arr = new T[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i)
    {
        arreay[i] = arr[i];
    }
    arreay[index] = item;
    for (int i = index + 1; i < size; ++i)
    {
        arreay[i] = arr[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84864/discussion-on-question-by----remove-----).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простая реализация списка на базе массива:

1. Храним сам массив элементов (`elemenets`)
2. Храним реальное количество элементов в массиве (`size`). Это позволит не пересоздавать массив при вызове метода `Remove`, а также иметь изначально массив не нулевого размера и увеличивать размер массива "с запасом" (для упрощения в примере кода массив увеличивается только до требуемого размера)

Метод `Insert(int index, T item)`:

1. Проверяет что `index` допустим
2. Проверяет что в массив войдёт ещё один элемент (`size + 1`) и, при необходимости, увеличивает размер массива
3. Сдвигает элементы в массиве от `index` до `size` вправо на одну позицию (`index` -> `index + 1`, ..., `size - 1` -> `size`)
4. Добавляет новый элемент по индексу `index`
5. Увеличивает `size` на единицу

Метод `Remove(T item)`:

1. Ищет первое вхождение `item` в массив
2. Если элемент найден (его `index` больше либо равен 0), то:

   - Сдвигает элементы с `index` до `size` влево на одну позицию (`index` <- `index + 1`, ..., `size - 1` <- `size`)
   - Уменьшает `size` на единицу

Метод `Add(T item)` (в вопросе про него речь не шла, но он короткий и всё равно его пришлось писать для тестирования кода):

1. Проверяет что в массив войдёт ещё один элемент (`size + 1`) и, при необходимости, увеличивает размер массива
2. Добавляет новый элемент в конец массива (по индексу `size`)
3. Увеличивает `size` на единицу

Пример кода:

```
public class MyList<T>
{
    private T[] elements = new T[5];

    private int size = 0;

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= size)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"Index: {index}, Size: {size}");

        EnsureCapacity(size + 1);

        for (var i = size; i > index; i--)
            elements[i] = elements[i - 1];

        elements[index] = item;
        size++;
    }

    public void Remove(T item)
    {
        var index = Array.IndexOf(elements, item, 0, size);

        if (index < 0)
            return;

        for (var i = index; i < size - 1; i++)
            elements[i] = elements[i + 1];

        size--;
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        EnsureCapacity(size + 1);

        elements[size] = item;
        size++;
    }

    private void EnsureCapacity(int capacity)
    {
        if (elements.Length < capacity)
        {
            var arr = new T[capacity];
            Array.Copy(elements, arr, size);
            elements = arr;
        }
    }
}
```